# How to store small amounts of gas

Tags: experimental-chemistry, water, home-experiment, noble-gases, separation-techniques

I need to store small amounts of gas. I already saw devices that look similar to the image below, but I don't know how they are called. Does someone here know how these devices are called? I am also open for alternative ideas. I mainly need some kind of storing devices that works with low pressure and that is capable of pushing the gas back if pressure is removed. A ballon for example wouldnt work since it requires to much force to get the gas inside. It would be awesome if someone here know more and can help me with this.

[image]

Comment: More of an engineering problem than a chemistry problem. What gasses? How much gas do you want to store? What/how do you want to use it?

Comment: No idea, but you should have a thick glasware catalogue somewhere in your lab. It´s bound to be in there. (Btw. your nick has one letter missing. Hopfenkaltschale?)

Answer (score 1):

A rubber balloon does require some force to get filled. A mylar balloon (typically filled with helium) can be purchased empty (or can be emptied) and requires almost no force to fill; then can be squashed manually to eject the gas. They are available in many sizes.

Rubber balloons also tend to go flat or leak, so their storage utility, especially for low m.w. gases, is short-term (a day or so). Aluminized mylar balloons can hold helium or hydrogen for long periods (weeks and even a month or two). For short-term, you could also use a plain polyethylene sandwich bag - after all, many objects are shipped with bags of air in the boxes to help protect them from damage. Use a needle to insert the gas and retrieve it; tape the area around the needle insertion - like an intravenous operation! Or, you can tape a plastic or glass tube into the bag.

Longer storage would require a gas sampling or collection tube, a glass container with a valve at one or both ends. The internet has many references to these.